# 401 Unauthorized error with Jawbone Up API and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth, httparty

I am trying to access the Jawbone API via Omniauth, HTTParty & Ruby on Rails. I'm passing the header Authorization => Bearer: [token_here] as required by the API docs, but it's still giving me a 401 error and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm able to successfully get the token via omniauth and store it to session[:token], but the API returns 401 unauthorized.

API documentation: https://jawbone.com/up/developer/authentication

I've searched stack overflow and couldn't find a solution to this. What's the problem?

My code is:

### sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

if session[:user_id]
    #if there's a session, then create the authorization
    User.find(session[:user_id]).add_provider(auth_hash)

else 
    auth = Authorization.find_or_create(auth_hash)
    session[:user_id] = auth.user.id
    session[:token] = auth.user.authorizations.first.token


end
redirect_to '/today'
end
```

### data_processor.rb

```
class DataProcessorController < ApplicationController
  def today
    @current_user_dp = session[:user_id]
    @token_dp = session[:token]
    @authorization_dp = "Bearer " + @token_dp
    #@auth = "Bearer " + session[:current_user].authorizations.first.token unless session[:user_id].nil?
    @result = HTTParty.get('http://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/goals',
                           :headers => { "Authorization" => @authorization_dp, "Accept" => "application/json"}) unless session[:token].nil?

  end
end
```

### results.html.erb

```
<p>Result: <%= @result %></p>
<p>Auth header: <%= @result.request.inspect%></p>
```

### output of HTML file:

```
Result: {"meta"=>{"code"=>401, "error_detail"=>"You must be logged in to perform that action", "error_type"=>"authentication_error", "message"=>"Unauthorized"}, "data"=>{}}

Auth header: #<HTTParty::Request:0x007fe446bb3320 @http_method=Net::HTTP::Get, @path=#<URI::HTTPS:0x007fe446bbb408 URL:https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/goals>, @options={:limit=>4, :default_params=>{}, :follow_redirects=>true, :parser=>HTTParty::Parser, :connection_adapter=>HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter, :headers=>{"Authorization"=>"Bearer XXXXXXXXXTOKEN_HEREXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "Accept"=>"application/json"}}, @last_uri=#<URI::HTTPS:0x007fe446bba918 URL:https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/goals>, @raw_request=#<Net::HTTP::Get GET>, @last_response=#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>, @redirect=true>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  If so, what as the solution? I'm having a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve this?

If you look at the other error fields it may give you more information. In my case I was getting 'unauthorized scope'. I was requesting items in a scope that I hadn't included in my original oauth request so the token I was providing had limited scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scope when you first authorize user.  I used `scope=move_read` and was able to get data from `http://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/goals`.